# jQuery.get(' not getting file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying

`jQuery.get('similar_products_stack.php');`

and

`jQuery.get('./similar_products_stack.php');`

Where similar_products_stack.php returns an html array and I am getting error 404 that the file is not found even though both files are in the same directory.

what am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: try loading similar_products_stack.php, are you getting the file in the browser?

Comment: Does the page open when accessed directly from the address bar?

Comment: try going to /similar_products_stack.php directly in your browser. What happens?

Comment: I can echo it out from another php file but it wont work with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) call is fine, although it won't have much effect (since you're not doing anything once you've gotten the file). If you want to load it into somewhere on the DOM, you might look at [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

If you're *really* getting a 404, that suggests that either you're mistaken that the files are in the same directory (more accurately, on the same path) on the server, or there's a permissions problem, redirects issue, etc. that prevents the server from accessing / running / returning results from the PHP file. All sorts of other symptoms might be more mysterious, but if the server is really reporting 404, it means that the resource cannot be found (or that the settings — e.g., permissions — don't allow the server to admit to finding it).

Comment: It wont load from the browser because of my setup, however it will echo the contents out if I get it from PHP and use foreach

Comment: *"It wont load from the browser because of my setup"* If your browser can't retrieve it, that's your problem. `$.get` evaluates, in the end, to a *browser* request for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using absolute urls for ajax calls '/dir/similar_products_stack.php'